# Subset a Python 3.x dataframe based on a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` and a list `in_list` with several users IDs. I want to create multiple dataframes based on the user ID of `in_list`.

Here is the list:

```
in_list = 
[4638472273,
 1559410755,
 4931532174,
 2419930464,
 1884182865,
 3688089071,
 4555003213,
 2068627935,
 2894365987,
 8549533077]
```

And here is the code:

```
i = 0
while i < len(in_list):
    user_index[i] = df[(df.In == in_list[i])] 
    i += 1
```

When I execute the above code I get this error message `ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series`.

I want to create several dataframes called `user_index0`, `user_index1`, `user_index2`, etc. with the subset of the dataframe `df`but I'm getting this error.

Comment: Can you share your required output data frame? What is user_index?

Comment: `user_index[i] = df[(df.In == in_list[i])]`  ->>>> the user_index[i] would lead to user_index being a dictionary and the value of i as the key. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily acomplish this using a list comprehension:

```
df_list = [df[df.In == i] for i in in_list]
```

Then, if you want a dictionary just do:

```
df_dict = dict(zip(range(0,len(in_list)), df_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using `isin` to filter your dataframe to first match 'in_list' then `groupby` 'in' and `append` results of a group to 'user_index' list:

```
user_index = []
for _,g in df[df['in'].isin(in_list)].groupby('in'):
    user_index.append(g)
```